# Connection string in Visual Studio for Database Access

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, ms-access-2007

My Access database is password: (password is '123')

What is the connection code in C#?

SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
**cnn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=G:\My Project\DB.accdb;user=Admin;pwd=123";**
cnn.open();

'ERROR Connection'

Comment: The `SqlConnection` class is used for SQL Server. Use an `OleDbConnection`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct connection string for Microsoft Access is something like this

```
@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; 
 Data Source=G:\My Project\DB.accdb;
 Jet OLEDB:Database Password=123;"
```

Of course you should use the appropriate provider. SqlConnection and the other classes from the namespace `System.Data.SqlClient` are used for Sql Server. Microsoft Access should uses the classes from the namespace `System.Data.OleDb` like `OleDbConnection`, `OleDbCommand`, `OleDbDataReader` etc...

Answer (score 1):

This might help you out

```
  Private connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=G:\My Project\DB.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=123;"

  SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connString);

  cnn.open();
  //Do your Work
```

If you are using Microsoft Access accdb ODBC Driver

```
 Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=G:\mydatabase.accdb;Uid=Admin;Pwd=123;
```